# Have I completely broken this chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I unsoldered all the connections from the bottom of the chip (ta8229k) but unfortently I was abit overzealous with trying to wiggle it off using the heat sink and its ended up snapping the top of chip off where the case was directly above the screw its got too bits of wire that to me look like copper, however I have no idea what silicon would look like inside a chip. Ive tried to find an internal layout of the chip with no luck, but have looked at similar circuits such as
[image]
Where it looks like the wire at the top is just a wire - the 2 pieces of maybe copper are about 1 mm thick (but it is supposed to be a 30 watt amplifier).

If I solder the 2 bits back together, will it save the chip or is beyond saving?

The Chip
[image: the chip]

Not the clearest picture but you can see the stripped away copper at the top, there is a break in between the 2 pieces but I've pushed them back together for the moment

Comment: Can you show an image of your chip?

Comment: Im struggling to get it to fit into the 2mb limit, but hopefully will have one up in a min

Comment: @Bren Just resize it. Modern cameras always seem to take photos in ridiculous resolution for no apparent reason, and if you shrink it to be like 1280×800 or something it'll be much more reasonable.

Comment: It's likely that the actual silicon chip is down below the hole in the middle of the package. That metal piece you broke is probably an extended part of the lead-frame intended to better distribute heat throughout the package. It'll almost certainly still work fine.

Comment: I'm going to guess you broke one or more of the bond wires.  If that's the case, the chip is toast, IMO.

Comment: @Bren The 2MB limit is easy to hit when copy-pasting the image, since that means you'll be uploading a PNG. For JPEGs, they'll have plenty of detail at 2MB size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I solder the 2 bits back together, will it save the chip or is
> beyond saving?

The top part may not be connected to the silicon, it does have a small bit of copper that could be however. I'd probably give it a shot.

It really comes down to what your willing to spend in time and effort. If you don't mind resoldering the chip back to the board to see if it works, then give it a shot. If it doesn't work, then you'll have to order a new ta8229k and unsolder the old one and install the new one that has a high probability of working.